# multi module configuration missing classes

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

we currently use a multi module configuration as it is described here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages
We use "Way#1" with the central configuration file in the root folder.

We analyse our code with the standalone scanner invoked from the command line.
The Scan runs fine, but we get a lot of warnings like:
"WARN: Bytecode of dependencies was not provided..."
"WARN: Classes not found during the analysis : [...]"
"The following classes needed for analysis were missing:..."

The listed Classes often belong to other module e.g. module1 can't reach the classes from module2.

A little hint what's missing in our configuration file would be very helpful.
We use the SonarJava, PMD and FindBugs Plugin.

Thanks
Marco

Comment: Those warnings are produced by SonarJava : what is the version you are using ? Are you setting sonar.java.libraries property properly ?

Comment: We use SonarJava 4.15.0.12310.
We currently do not use sonar.java.libraries properly, that is part of the problem for sure.

How do I configure the configuration file for the following situation:  

Submodule1 has a src and lib folder, Submodule2 has a src folder, submodule2 needs to see the Classes in src and the jars in lib of submodule1.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue? Please add an answer if you did.